# Having a delay in between tasks submitted to Executor Service

Tags: java, executorservice

I am using spring-boot and I have this use case where I want to submit each of the element of the list to the executor service (threadpool size = 4). But in between each of the element which has to be processed, I want a delay of 1 second.

Thread.sleep(1000) doesn't work because Executor starts another thread as soon as one goes to sleep.

```
        list().forEach(key -> {
            executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    process(key);
                }
            });
        });
```

Edit : This is my process() method where I tried using sleep at the end but it didn't work.

```
    private void process(long key) {
        try {
            //processing key

        } catch (SystemException e) {
            // Exception handling
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
```

Comment: Use tags to describe what your question is about, not what it contains. Just because your app is using Spring Boot, doesn't mean you need to use [spring-boot] automatically. Your question has nothing to do with Spring Boot but `ExecutorService` only.

Comment: Two questions: 1.: "But in between each of the element which has to be processed, I want a delay of 1 second.", why? 2.: Where did you try putting `Thread.sleep(1000)`?

Comment: Please provide a code where you create your `executorService`

Comment: Why don't you make the main Thread sleep in between submissions to your executorService?

Comment: Since you want them to execute sequentially on another thread, why not just use a `ScheduledExecutorService` and poll the list?

Comment: @akuzminykh I need a second's wait because the service I am calling for the processing cant handle so much load and I have thousands of elements in my list.
Edited the question to show where i used thread.sleep().

Comment: @Jason If I am correct, ScheduledExecutorService is used for running a particular task periodically, but what do you mean by poll the list?

Comment: I posted an answer below with some information @AnmolAeron

Answer (score 0):

Since you want them to execute sequentially on another thread, why not just use a `ScheduledExecutorService` and poll the list?

*pseudo*

```java
Iterator<Pojo> iterator = list().iterator();

Future<Pojo> future = executorService.schedule(() -> {
    if (!iterator.hasNext()) {
        future.cancel(false);
        return;
    }
    Pojo pojo = iterator.next();
    
    iterator.remove();

    process(pojo.key());
}
```